# How to get the current screensaver on Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, registry, screensaver, windows-screensaver

Either using Regedit or using command prompt, I need to learn the active screensaver file. Without using the screensaver settings window, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" -v sc*
```

> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop
>     ScreenSaveActive    REG_SZ    1
>     ScreenSaverIsSecure    REG_SZ    0
>     ScreenSaveTimeOut    REG_SZ    300
>     SCRNSAVE.EXE    REG_SZ    C:\WINDOWS\system32\Mystify.scr
>
> End of search: 4 match(es) found.
> ```

Above code works for standard Windows screensavers (defined as follows and *Blank*); didn't try *Photos*.

```
reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Screensavers"
```

> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Screensavers\Bubbles
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Screensavers\Mystify
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Screensavers\Ribbons
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Screensavers\ssText3d
> ```

Possible executables:

```
where *.scr
```

> ```
> C:\Windows\System32\Bubbles.scr
> C:\Windows\System32\Mystify.scr
> C:\Windows\System32\PhotoScreensaver.scr
> C:\Windows\System32\Ribbons.scr
> C:\Windows\System32\scrnsave.scr
> C:\Windows\System32\ssText3d.scr
> ```